# Connect cloudfront with Elastic Beanstalk Application

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-elb

I am trying to connect cloudfront with EBS.

**Whats the setup?**

- EBS is hosting a nodeJs application.
- Cloudfront origin set to Elastic load balancer and accepts HTTPS
  only [Cloudfront config]
- All Alternative domains are added correctly.
- ACM certificate is added to Cloudfront [region US EAST - N.Virgina]
- EC2 instance / EBS is in the region Asia Pacific. ACM certificates
  installed in load balancer are from Asia pacific too.

I am also redirecting http traffic with the help of load balancer listeners.

[image]

Security group allows traffic to port 443 .
No AWS WAF set.

Origin settings:-

[image]

It's been a day now.

I am trying continuously.

I am able to set DNS A & AAA record to the cloudfront using route 53, getting the dropdown value as well.

I am able to park domains directly to EBS & they work over https properly.

Getting 502 ERROR : The request could not be satisfied.

Already tried https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/resolve-cloudfront-bad-request-error/

I doubt my ELB has ACM certificate from **Asia Pacific** but the ACM certificate used in cloudfront is from **US EAST** , is that causing the issue? I can't change the EBS region now.

Comment: Can you access your EB directly using HTTPS? Does it work well without CF?

Comment: Yes, It shows SSL error. [Your connection to this site is not secure] But I can access. @Marcin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you did not [setup https on your EB](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/elastic-beanstalk-https-configuration/). But you are using `HTTPS only` origin. That's why it does not work. You have to have origin in http, or actually properly setup https on your EB.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. 

I am able to add domains directly with EBS and they work over https. With SSL certificates from ACM into ELB. 

But doing through cloudfront is not working.
If i don't set HTTPS only, it is creating a redirect to the naked EBS domain.

Comment: @XenonCI Your origin must be your custom domain which works over HTTPS. you can't connect to the default EB url, as this is only for HTTP.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Marcin for finding out my stupid mistake!

It was because of the ELB not accepting

> https only

config from cloudfront.
But i had set listeners to redirect all HTTP traffic to HTTPS,
and HTTPS traffic points to my instance.

After finding out the reason mentioned by @Marcin

**How i solved the problem:**

- Changed cloudfront origin request to http only.
- Set a custom header :

[image]

- then added a new listener to ELB which forwards to my instance if the header match, it would help EBS differentiate requests from Cloudfront and other origins.

[image]

Still i was getting same response, found out the response was from cache. Just had to invalidate cache of cloudfront. And its done!

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/Invalidation.html